# How to get page.js to work in a single page AND multipage on the same site?

Tags: javascript, singlepage, page.js

am using page.js for routing in a Grails application using '/' to point /HomeController/index to serve up a single page web application. I just installed Grails Spring Security Core plugin, and I am using the Grails scaffolding to create the User Admin/Permissions views with the goal of serving them in the traditional multi-page way to avoid having to do a lot of UI work on admin pages. The bulk of the application will be served using single page architecture, with just the admin pages being served multi-page.

In their documentation, page.js says, "By default when a route is not matched, page.js will invoke page.stop() to unbind itself, and proceed with redirecting to the location requested. This means you may use page.js with a multi-page application without explicitly binding to certain links."  But, I cannot get it to work...

I am using page.js like so:

```
page('/', SCM.Dashboard.home);
page('/hx', SCM.HX.summary);
page('/hx/vendor', SCM.HX.vendors);
page('/hx/customer', SCM.HX.customers);
page('/customer/list', SCM.Customer.list);
page('/maintenance/activity', SCM.Maintenance.activity);
page();
```

When I click a link to '/user', based on their documentation, I expect it to forward directly to 'http://domain.com/user'. It adds the correct path to browser location bar (http://domain.com/user), but the browser never forwards to the page. In order to see the page, I have to click the link, and after the location bar has changed, if I refresh the browser window, the correct page appears - obviously unacceptable. Yet, I cannot find in their documentation how to implement this correctly. I have experimented with various settings for hours with no luck. If I comment out the page.js code above, the multi-page admin pages work fine, and I am able to navigate from page to page no problem. Has anyone solved this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just upgraded from version 1.4.0 to version 1.5.0 and it links between the Single page (Main app) and Multi-page (Admin functionality) portions of the application seamlessly with no configuration needed!! Excellent feature addition!